# Cannot Upload HealthKitData in the Background

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, background-task

I am having some trouble with uploading HealthKit data to AWS S3 in the background. As of now, when I click on the button to beginBackgroundUpdates the data is uploaded as expected. When I go off the app and add data to HealthKit nothing happens. When I go back to the app, the new data is uploaded. I am not sure why this is not happening in the background. More specifically, I am not sure if this is allowed, and if so what I am doing wrong.

Initially, I wasn't using a completion handler for the data upload task, but I found someone having a similar problem as myself, except with firebase, and they found that implementing a completion handler on the data upload function fixed the problem. Here are all the functions and views that I am using:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var healthKitManager = HealthKitManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Enable Background Step Delivery") {
                healthKitManager.beginBackgroundUpdates()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            healthKitManager.requestAuthorization { success in
                print("Configured HealthKit with Return: \(success)")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

BackgroundDeliveryApp:

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit
import Amplify
import AWSS3StoragePlugin
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin

@main
struct HKBackgruondDeliveryApp: App {
    
    private func configureAmplify() {
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("Succesfully configured Amplify with S3 Storage")
        } catch {
            print("Could not configure Amplify")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        configureAmplify()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

HealthKitManager

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit
import Amplify

struct TestStep: Encodable, Decodable {
    let count: Double
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
    let device: String
}

class HealthKitManager: ObservableObject {
    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    let stepType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)
    let heartRateType = HKQuantityType(.heartRate)
    let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .sleepAnalysis)
    
    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        } else {
            print("There is no health data available")
            healthStore = nil
        }
    }
    
    func encodeStepList(stepList: [TestStep]) -> Data{
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
        
        do {
            return try encoder.encode(stepList)
        } catch {
            return Data()
        }
    }
    
    func uploadStepData(stepList: [TestStep]) async {
        let stepData = self.encodeStepList(stepList: stepList)
        
        let uploadTask = Amplify.Storage.uploadData(
            key: "ExampleKey",
            data: stepData
        )
        Task {
            for await progress in await uploadTask.progress {
                print("Progress: \(progress)")
            }
        }
        do {
            let value = try await uploadTask.value
            print("Completed: \(value)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not upload step data")
        }
        
    }
    
    func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
                
        guard let stepType = stepType, let sleepType = sleepType else {
            return completion(false)
        }
        
        guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else {
            return completion(false)
        }
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [stepType, heartRateType, sleepType]) { success, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Some error has occoured during authorization of healthKit")
                print(error)
            }
            
            return completion(success)
        }
    }
    
    func beginBackgroundUpdates() {
        guard let healthStore = healthStore, let stepType = stepType else {
            print("Cannot begin background updates because HealthStore is nil")
            return
        }
        
        healthStore.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: stepType, frequency: .immediate) { success, error in
            print("Background update of health data")
            if let error = error {
                print("Some error has occoured during the set up of the background observer query for steps")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let query = self.createObserverQuery() else {
                print("Could not create a query for steps")
                return
            }
            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
        
    }
    
    func stepCountDeviceRecordsQuery(stepCountObjects: @escaping ([TestStep]) -> Void) {
        guard let stepType = stepType else {
            print("Nil step type")
            return
        }
        
        let stepCountUnit = HKUnit.count()
        let endDate = Date()
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: endDate)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate)
        let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true)]
        
        let stepCountQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: stepType, predicate: predicate, limit: 10000, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors) { query, results, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in getStepCount")
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let results = results else {
                print("Empty results in getStepCount")
                return
            }
            var stepCounts: [TestStep] = []
            for (_, record) in results.enumerated() {
                guard let record: HKQuantitySample = record as? HKQuantitySample else {return}
                let step = TestStep(count: record.quantity.doubleValue(for: stepCountUnit), startDate: record.startDate, endDate: record.endDate, device: record.device?.model ?? "")
                stepCounts.append(step)
            }
            print("\(stepCounts.count) records at \(Date())")
            print(stepCounts[stepCounts.count - 1])
            
            stepCountObjects(stepCounts)
        }
        
        healthStore?.execute(stepCountQuery)
    }
    
    private func createObserverQuery() -> HKQuery? {
        guard let stepType = stepType else {
            return nil
        }
        let query = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: stepType, predicate: nil) { query, completionHandler, error in
            
            self.stepCountDeviceRecordsQuery { stepList in
                Task {
                    await self.uploadStepData(stepList: stepList)
                }
            }
            completionHandler()
        }
        return query
    }
}
```